# How to obtain a data set from PostgreSQL 9.0 Function ("stored procedure")

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, dataset

I'm trying to obtain a data set from a PostgreSQL 9.0 function and I'm not able to with stored procedures.

I'm new to Postgres this week so let me explain my terms:

In pgAdmin III I can enter the command:

```
SELECT * FROM member;
```

And receive the following Data Output:

```
memberid   membername
1          Bill Smith
2          Joe Smith
```

I tried creating MANY functions (tables / SETOF / etc) pretty much like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_members()
RETURNS SET OF member AS
'select * from member;'
```

When I run them in pgAdmin (or call them from a program) I get the following:

```
SELECT get_all_members()
```

Results:

```
get_all_members
member
(1, "Bill Smith")
(2, "Joe Smith")
```

Is there anyway to get this as a data set from a FUNCTION (Stored Procedure) as I can with directly entering SQL commands.

You help is GREATLY appreciated!!!

Comment: That output is a single column containing a *record*, which is a kind of *composite type*. PostgreSQL supports treating rows as values. `SELECT get_all_members()` is doing the equivalent of `SELECT x FROM get_all_members() x` when you want `SELECT * FROM get_all_members()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the per column output by modifying your select statement a bit so it looks like so:

```
SELECT * FROM get_all_members()
```

This will give you the column by column output just like doing the query normally.

See [set returning functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I get the same result.  Actually pgAdmin III had added the LANGUAGE SQL for me.

Comment: I've modified by answer, I thought the LANGUAGE SQL solved it but you need to modify the subsequent SQL query where you try to get the data from the function so it looks like: `SELECT * FROM get_all_members()`

Comment: No problem. Welcome to StackOverflow! If you found the answer helpful/solved, mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark on the side of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Suhail - I clicked the check - since I'm new today I can't "vote up" your answer!!!