# Extracting results from a SELECT * in node pg

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql-9.2, stored-functions

I have a Postgresql stored function defined as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SessionGet(
    sid            varchar)
    RETURNS "SESSION" AS $$
    SELECT * FROM "SESSION" WHERE "SESSION_ID" = sid;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

I call it from node using the PG module with:

```
SELECT SessionGet('SID-1'::varchar);
```

The `session` table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE "SESSION"
(
  "SESSION_ID" character varying NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  "SESSION" json NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::json,
  "LAST_UPDATE" bigint DEFAULT 0,
  CONSTRAINT "SESSION_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SESSION_ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

I am trying to retrieve the returned result as following:

```
client.query(sql, function(err, result) {
            done(); // Releasing connection to the pool
            if ( err ) {
                callback(err);
            } else if ( result.rows.length > 0 ) {
                var ttmp = result.rows[0];
                var tmp1 = ttmp[0];
                console.log("Res[0]: " + tmp1);
                callback(err,result.rows[0]);
            } else {
                callback(err);
            }
        });
```

Although `result.rows.length` is `> 0`, `result.rows[0][0]` is undefined. How can I retrieve the field values from the returned row?

Comment: Are you sure your function is returning a non-null value? Call it in `psql` with the same input and see.

Comment: When I call the function from pgAdmin' sql window, I get: "(SID-1,{},10)". May node's pg module does not handle this result properly...

Comment: When I run: SELECT * FROM "SESSION" WHERE "SESSION_ID" = 'SID-1'; the result comes in 3 different colums, rather than with (,,)

Comment: Ah, you would've needed to run `SELECT * FROM SessionGet('SID-1'::varchar);` to get the right answer then.

Comment: I could test it and you are right. And it is a duplicate question too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain a data set from PostgreSQL 9.0 Function ("stored procedure")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110649/how-to-obtain-a-data-set-from-postgresql-9-0-function-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by sending a SQL statement (`SELECT * FROM "SESSION" WHERE "SESSION_ID" = '...';`) rather than relying on a stored function.

I have also changed the name of the `SESSION` column to `SESSION_JS`, as giving the name of a table to a column too seems to be an issue, though no error message is displayed.